# Is it advisable to bucket on more than one columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I am trying to group by col1,col2,col3,col4 in my hive SQL query in a  table partitioned on date.The table has 365 partitions and around 40 G of data. Is it advisable to bucket the data on 4 columns ?My understanding is it is same as increasing the number of reducers.Any thoughts ?

Comment: So you partitioned by day? Wouldn't it be better to partition by year, then month?

Comment: One of key optimization techniques is to minimize the number of files and directories created.So the idea of partitioning with year ,then month is questionable in my mind. Also my question is more on clustering the columns to buckets to provide better sampling. Does it has any relation with number of reducers ?

Comment: 365 (for days, I assume) produces much more files than partitioning by year then month.  I can't remember the relation of reducers to partitions, but think about a phonebook to look for a number. You lookup  the first letter first, then the second letter, etc. That's the same idea as year and month vs just day. You are minimizing the data to read by partitioning.